# Configure git-lfs to track files above some size

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I have a git repository with git-lfs installed and I would like to have *all PDF files above some size* in LFS, but not *all PDF files*, as git-lfs supports. The reason for this is that I have many tiny PDF figure files in vector format which are ok to have in regular version control, and a few large PDFs.

Is it possible to configure git-lfs this way?

I use git from Atlassian source-tree and host the repository in bitbucket, maybe those support this more advanced use-case?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Didn't find a solution, no.

Comment: Annoying, I have the same problem. But thanks for responding so quickly

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is not possible on git-lfs. See issue [#282](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/282).

There is however a [hack](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/282#issuecomment-463262318) provided by user Baccanno, but I wouldn't recommend it for repositories with many files. It tracks ***all*** files above a threshold, but it *could* be modified to do it for PDF's only.

#### The hack:

(Copied here without warranty)

Put this in the `[alias]` section of your git config (`project_root/.git/config`) and change the 300k at the end to the size you wish

```
track-large = !"git st --porcelain --ignore-submodules | grep -v \"D \" | awk '{ l=length($0); s=substr($0,4,l-1); print s}' | sed -n 's/\\(\\(.* -> *\\)\\|\\)\\(.*\\)/\\3/p' | xargs -I{} find {} -size +300k | xargs -I{} git lfs track \"{}\""
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm the original author, it's suboptimal and I went from this to a more dense .gitattribute that covers all the binaries in our game. The only issue remaining is with Unity files that are text based (which is good), such as `.asset`, but that can get greatly vary in size (which is bad). You'd have the same issue with any text based representation of large data. In this case I would still recommend to check them manually with this kind of workaround, or any similar such as this lfs-auto-track repo (didn't check it myself)